# Ширина CTk.Frame в customTkinter

Tags: python, customtkinter

Задаю явно ширину фрейма, но результата нет.
Пример кода:

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image

from system_info_frame import SystemFrame
from info_frame import InfoFrame
from settings_frame import SettingsFrame
from analyze_frame import AnalyzeFrame


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Cleaner")
        self.geometry("820x650")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(fg_color="#58259c")

        self.system_info_frame = SystemFrame(master=self, fg_color="#6A46AA")
        self.system_info_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.info_frame = InfoFrame(master=self, fg_color="#6A46AA", width=245)
        self.info_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.settings_frame = AnalyzeFrame(master=self, fg_color="#6A46AA", width=245)
        self.settings_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.settings_frame = SettingsFrame(master=self, fg_color="#6A46AA", width=245)
        self.settings_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.btn_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("scan.png"), size=(150, 150))
        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, text="", image=self.btn_image, hover_color="#58259c",
                                              fg_color="#58259c", command=self.button_function)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

    def button_function(self):
        print("button pressed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Пример одно из фреймов:

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image


class InfoFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.disk_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("disk.png"), size=(100, 100))
        self.label_disk = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self, text="", image=self.disk_image, width=150)
        self.label_disk.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0), sticky="ew")

        self.label_info = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self, text="Cleanup",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Montserrat", size=14, weight="bold"),
                                                 text_color="white")
        self.label_info.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=0, sticky="ew")

        text = "Clears temporary files from Temp folders\nClearing Temporary Browser Files\nCleanup " \
               "Windows update files\nCleaning the Downloads folder"
        self.label_info_description = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self, text=text,
                                                             font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Montserrat", size=12),
                                                             text_color="#A2A3D3", justify="left")
        self.label_info_description.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=(0, 10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = InfoFrame()
    app.mainloop()
```